# How to retrieve a file using node.js fs readFile function without specifying the name?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm currently stuck trying to retrieve a file from file system in order to send it through api to the client. For my backend I'm using express js
I'm using `fs` library and currently I'm trying to do it with `readFile` function, but I want to do it without specifying the file name or just the file extension because it will depend from file file will be uploaded from client.

What I tried until now (unsuccessfully) is shown below:

```
router.get("/info/pic", async (req, res) => {
  const file = await fs.readFile("./images/profile/me.*", (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);  // Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './images/profile/me.*'
      return;
    }
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

```
const file = await fs.readFile("./images/profile/*.*", (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);  // Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './images/profile/*.*'
      return;
    }
    console.log(data);
});
```

```
const file = await fs.readFile("./images/profile/*", (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);  // Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './images/profile/*'
      return;
    }
    console.log(data);
});
```

If I specify the file name everything works fine, like: `fs.readFile("./images/profile/me.jpg"`. but as I said, I don't know for sure the right extension of that file.

**Important info:** In that directory there will be only one file!

Please help me!
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If there is only one file in the directory, the following loop will have only one iteration:

```js
for await (const file of fs.opendirSync("./images/profile")) {
  var image = fs.readFileSync("./images/profile/" + file.name);
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const fs = require('fs');
fs.readdir('./images/profile', function (err, files) {
    //handling error
    if (err) {
        return console.log('err);
    } 
    files.forEach(function (file) {
        // Do whatever you want to do with the file
    });
});
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.